# Woocommerce: updating an order based on (Gravity) form submission

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Based on the how a form is populated, I want to update a pre-existing Woocommerce order. Has anyone tried this? I was looking at using the [Woocommerce REST API for updating orders](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-an-order), but it seems like there should be another way when everything is on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of gform_after_submission and update_post_meta.  A good trick is if you can store the order number you need to update in the gravity form itself:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_3', 'update_woocommerce_order', 10, 2 );//replace 3 with your form id
    function update_woocommerce_order($entry, $form ){
     if($entry['2'] == 'Test Value'){//This could be your form condition to trigger update
       $order_id = $entry['6'];// replace 6 with the form field number that contains the order number
       $phone = $entry['7'];// replace 7 with the form field number that contains the phone number
       update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_phone', $phone );   
     }
    }
```